# Devise test database records conflicts on simultaneous tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, tdd, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I generate Users, Clients and Invoices from the following factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com" }
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
  end

  factory :client do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Client Name #{n}" }
    sequence(:address1) { |n| "#{n} Street name" }
    sequence(:address2) { |n| "#{n} Area name" }
    city "Chennai"
    state "Tamil Nadu"
    country "India"
    zipcode "600001"
    contactname "Sathish Manohar"
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}
    user
  end

  factory :invoice do
    client
  end
end
```

I have some requests and model specs, following are the main request specs I have:

https://gist.github.com/4418869 - clients_pages_spec.rb
https://gist.github.com/4418876 - invoices_pages_spec.rb

When all `users` are deleted in an `after(:all) { User.delete_all }` call, all tests are passing when run in order using `bundle exec rspec spec --order default`

When all `users` are not deleted in `after(:all) { User.delete_all }`, then the email uniqueness error shows up while running tests. It is the error from devise to validate uniqueness of each user's email, So I think when running tests for the second time, `factory_girl` tries to create the same users.

This is the error message:

`` /home/sathish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@invoice_jet/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/validations.rb:56:in `save!': Validation failed: Email has already been taken (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid) ``

How do I get rid of this error messages, and create devise users for testing the right way?

*Background information:*
`spec_helper.rb` has `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true`
using mysql as database all tables are using `InnoDB` engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you shall define a default strategy for cleaning up your database entirely after each spec and, by doing that, guarantee the isolation on each test.

Take a look at Database Cleaner gem on https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner.

All you have to do is put the gem in your Gemfile, run `bundle` (presuming you're using bundler) and define a strategy, as such:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I agree, tests should definitely be isolated, but in my experience it's better to clean database before each test, not after it. That way when something fails, you can look into the database and see problematic data afterwards.

Comment: Since the database is just a storage mechanism for your data, i dont really agree with your statement... Your objects model is your app and your database just provide you a way to keep the state of such objects by persisting them. Anyway, hope the DB Cleaner Gem helps you with your described problem

Comment: I am not the one who asked this question. I agree that database is just a storage for data, but database layer in your code can also be a source of bugs and it can be useful to look at actual stored data. Therefore I think that it's practice to clean database before each test, not afterwards. What disadvantages do you see compared to cleaning after each test?

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed... I don't see any disadvantages at all, i was just arguing the reason why.

Comment: Thanks! your answer along with this post, ( http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/ ) helped me fix the issue.

Seems I needed to set `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` as well.